# Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF9320CD29 when using minMaxLoc

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I need to get the maximum intensity pixel in an image. To do it I use `minMaxLoc` but it throws an exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF9320CD29 in opencv-test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000050347CF630.

I am using OpenCV 4.7.0.

My code is:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {

    string videoURL = "C:/Users/Downloads/kinect-depth-image.mp4";

    // set input video
    VideoCapture cap(videoURL);

    Mat frame;

    for (;;) {
        // get frame from the video
        cap >> frame;

        // stop the program if no more images
        if (frame.rows == 0 || frame.cols == 0)
            return 0;

        // show frame
        imshow("Frame", frame);
        waitKey(0);

        double minVal, maxVal;
        Point minLoc, maxLoc;
        minMaxLoc(frame, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
        std::cout << "Maximum value within image: " << maxVal << std::endl;

        // show frame
        imshow("Frame", frame);

        //quit on ESC button
        if (waitKey(1) == 27)break;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The exception appears in the line after the `minMaxLoc()` call.

The `imshow()` call shows the first frame of my video properly.

The exception goes away if I remove the parameters, `&minLoc` and `&maxLoc`, and `minVal` and `maxVal` contain values – but I need the location of the pixel too.

What is wrong? How can I fix that?

Comment: You can only pass single-channeled images to `cv::minMaxLoc()`. Are you sure your image is one channel only? It doesn't appear to be. See: https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab473bf2eb6d14ff97e89b355dac20707

Comment: You are right, @stateMachine! Converting the frame to grayscale first fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue thanks to the comment of @stateMachine, converting the frame to grayscale before executing `minMaxLoc`:

```
// Convert the image to grayscale
Mat gray;
cvtColor(frame, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

minMaxLoc(gray, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
```